# cannot run the cardboard demo on iOS device

Tags: ios, google-cardboard

I have done everything google developer website told,but the problem is Xcode still has some problems when compiling the demo project.

The problem is:ld:

> /Users/Day1/Desktop/temp files/New Unity Project 3/cardboarddeomsave2/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/libvrunity.a(unity-6C9520564923BB79.o) 
>       does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), 
>       obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
>       clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Another thing I have realize is that, before I compile the project, the right side of the Xcode scene has one area which is red. (libiconv.2.dylib is red) Is there any correlations here?

(By the way I have upgraded my OS X to OS X EI Captian beta and my Xcode is Xcode 7.0 beta)

Answer (score 4):

I was reaching this problem as well and this seemed to solve my problem. (It builds for me and deploys the application, but then fails to run while still connected. If I stop the connection and restart the app so that it is only running from the phone, it runs perfectly fine.)

1. In Xcode, select the folder view in the left pane top menu and
   select your project in the left pane.
2. Then in the menu above the main panel, select Build Settings.
3. In Build Settings, make sure that "All" is selected (not "Basic")
4. Scroll down to Build Options and set "Bitcode Enabled" to NO.

Comment: I was having the same problem the first night I tried to build to the device. Per anthony-n's answer, setting "Bitcode Enabled" to NO fixed my issue.